# Where did tox look when searching for "basepython"?

Tags: python, jenkins, cloudbees, pythonpath, tox

Currently, we have this in the `Build Environment` on cloudbees

```
curl -s -o use-python https://repository-cloudbees.forge.cloudbees.com/distributions/ci-addons/python/use-python
chmod u+x use-python

# Get all Python distributions from CloudBees
supported=("2.7.14" "3.4.7" "3.5.4" "3.6.4")
for version in "${supported[@]}"; do   
    export PYTHON_VERSION=$version
    . ./use-python
done

# Sanity checks.
python --version
python2 --version
python2.7 --version
python3 --version
python3.4 --version
python3.5 --version
python3.6 --version

which python
which python2
which python3

which python2.7
which python3.4
which python3.5
which python3.6
```

In the `tox.ini`, we've declared the `basepython=3.4` at line https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/tox.ini#L84

```
[testenv:py34-jenkins]
basepython = python3.4
commands = {toxinidir}/jenkins.sh
```

And our setup on the cloudbees CI server could find our Python3.4 interpreter, as we see with `which python`: https://nltk.ci.cloudbees.com/job/nltk/808/TOXENV=py34-jenkins,jdk=jdk8latestOnlineInstall/console

But when it ran `tox`, it threw and `InterpreterNotFound`:

```
+ which python3.4
/scratch/jenkins/python/python-3.4.7-x86_64/bin/python3.4
+ which python3.5
/scratch/jenkins/python/python-3.5.4-x86_64/bin/python3.5
+ which python3.6
/scratch/jenkins/python/python-3.6.4-x86_64/bin/python3.6
+ mkdir -p /home/jenkins/lib
+ '[' -f /home/jenkins/lib/libblas.so ']'
+ ln -sf /usr/lib64/libblas.so.3 /home/jenkins/lib/libblas.so
+ '[' -f /home/jenkins/lib/liblapack.so ']'
+ ln -sf /usr/lib64/liblapack.so.3 /home/jenkins/lib/liblapack.so
[EnvInject] - Script executed successfully.
[jdk8latestOnlineInstall] $ /scratch/jenkins/shiningpanda/jobs/280e15ca/tools/bin/python -c "import pip; pip.main();" install --upgrade tox
Requirement already up-to-date: tox in /scratch/jenkins/shiningpanda/jobs/280e15ca/tools/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Requirement already up-to-date: virtualenv>=1.11.2 in /scratch/jenkins/shiningpanda/jobs/280e15ca/tools/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from tox)
Requirement already up-to-date: six in /scratch/jenkins/shiningpanda/jobs/280e15ca/tools/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from tox)
Requirement already up-to-date: py>=1.4.17 in /scratch/jenkins/shiningpanda/jobs/280e15ca/tools/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from tox)
Requirement already up-to-date: pluggy<1.0,>=0.3.0 in /scratch/jenkins/shiningpanda/jobs/280e15ca/tools/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from tox)
You are using pip version 7.1.2, however version 9.0.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
[jdk8latestOnlineInstall] $ /scratch/jenkins/shiningpanda/jobs/280e15ca/tools/bin/python -c "import tox; tox.cmdline();" -c tox.ini
GLOB sdist-make: /scratch/jenkins/workspace/nltk/TOXENV/py34-jenkins/jdk/jdk8latestOnlineInstall/setup.py
py34-jenkins create: /scratch/jenkins/workspace/nltk/TOXENV/py34-jenkins/jdk/jdk8latestOnlineInstall/.tox/py34-jenkins
ERROR: InterpreterNotFound: python3.4
```

Couple of related questions:

- **Where did tox look when searching for `basepython`?**
- **Is it trying to look for PYTHONPATH?**
- **How can I setup the `tox` such that I append custom path(s) to where it should be looking for `basepython`?**
- **`python3.4` is inside the `PATH` environmental variable, why isn't `tox` looking there?**

Comment: Can you run the which commands after the `EnvInject`? Curious if that's modifying the world state. Also perhaps an `echo $PATH` for good measure

Comment: I've moved the python setup script from `Build Environment` to the `Shell` in `Build` before the `tox` execution and it's still gives the same error https://nltk.ci.cloudbees.com/job/nltk/TOXENV=py34-jenkins,jdk=jdk8latestOnlineInstall/812/console =(

Comment: hmmm, that's dangerously close to the shebang limit (127 characters), I wonder if that's causing issues.  Do you have ssh access to this jenkins machine I'd be curious to take a look at it.  I'll ping you on the tox issue :) (I also suspect some suspicious code in `tox` as well).

Comment: If anyone is interested in the long backstory and resolution of the related background to this question, see https://github.com/nltk/nltk/pull/1942